# WKWebView:Load contents from documents folder in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

In my app I have an index.html as part of resource bundle, it acts as a template. It has path to different resources. I load it into a WKWebview and when the app is online everything works fine, all resources are loaded from web and page is perfect.

In case of offline, I am downloading these resources to documents folder with in app and replace the online paths with offline path in the Index.html eg

```
    <image src = "file:///Users/an/Library/Developer/..../Library/Caches/MYApp/Icon.png">
   <a href="file:///Users/an/Library/Developer/..../Library/Caches/MYApp/Data.html">
```

But Index.html is unable to load it. I tried loading the Data.html directly into the webview using `wkWebView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "file:///Users/an/Library/Developer/..../Library/Caches/MYApp/Data.html")!))` and it works, but when I try to load it via Index.html, then it stops working.

Most people are telling to have a webserver like GCDWebServer and all, is that the only way? If I use it will this issue get resolved?

Comment: You should probably write a [MCVE] that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

My requirement was to load/ change a resource in Index.html from documents or caches folder at run time using java script. (*I am not at all hardcoding the paths and I am of-course using file manager*). While doing that I was unable to access resources using `file://` protocol. Today a I tried a sample app to demonstrate my problem and all of a sudden it starts working :). Now I need to visit my main project and see what is going wrong.

In this sample project I am trying to change the src of an image at run time by passing a path from the caches folder.

[WKWebViewAccessDocuments](https://github.com/anoop4real/WKWebViewAccessDocuments)

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking the OS for the location of the file you downloaded? The target directory can change without you being notified, and if you use a hard-coded location you won't be successful once the directory structure changes. You should get a url pointing to your user's writeable cache folders like this:

```
let userCachesDirectoryURL =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
```

Once you have that, you can append your filename (not the entire path) to that url. I just printed out the results of that line in one of my programs and saw a couple of folders being used by my app.

Give it a try and if you're still stuck, let me know. I can write up sample code... (as soon as I'm free).

Comment: I think I got the problem fixed.